# Get number of exact substrings

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to get the number of substrings out of a string.

The inputs are excel formulas like `IF(....IF(...))+IF(...)+SUM(..)` as a string. I want to count all `IF(` substrings. It's important that `SUMIF(...)` and `COUNTIF(...)` will not be counted.

I thought to check that there is no capital letter before the `"IF"`, but this is giving (certainly) index out of bound. Can someone give me a suggestion?

My code:

```
for(int i = input.indexOf("IF(",input.length()); 
        i != -1; 
        i= input.indexOf("IF(,i- 1)){

    if(!isCapitalLetter(tmpFormulaString, i-1)){
        ifStatementCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug your code and you'll find the problem in less than 13 seconds.

Comment: Can you make question more clear? Better question gets better answer also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you can do the parsing by yourself as you were doing (that's possibly better for you to learn debugging so you know what your problem is)

However it can be easily done by regular expression:

```
String s = "FOO()FOOL()SOMEFOO()FOO";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bFOO\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

int count = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    count++;
}

// count= 2
```

The main trick here is `\b` in the regex.  `\b` means word boundary.  In short, if there is a alphanumeric character at the position of `\b`, it will not match.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: This answer would be better if you told us what the `\b` actually means.

Comment: @DavidWallace No problem :)  In fact I leave it unmentioned intentionally because it should be something developers can easily find out by themselves.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I would like to upvote you now, after your edit; but I can't because I upvoted you before your edit.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was searching for. I think it's better to go with regex..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem by finding String `IF(`.

Try to do same thing in another way .

```
For example: 
inputStrin = IF(hello)IF(hello)....IF(helloIF(hello)).... 

inputString.getIndexOf("IF(");
```

That solves your problem?

[Click Here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) Or You can use `regular expression` also.

Comment: By the way, above answer is great then mine. :)It seems like best to use regular expression.